# "Comes at a very big price" or "comes at a very big effort"?

Tags: phrase-choice

"Comes at a very big price" or "comes at a very big effort"?

Which one is better for describing an action that is really hard for someone to perform? For example:

> He seems to have a problem talking to people. And this one is more of
>   a psychological nature, rather than merely of his character. Judging
>   by his facial expressions I can tell that he inderstands almost
>   everything that is being talked about but producing things **comes at
>   a very big price for** him or sometimes doesn't come at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither seem quite correct for the context.

Firstly the idiom you are referring to is normally "*comes at a very **high** price*". But this is normally used to show that there is a *cost*, not necessarily financial, but a personal cost, for example time or sacrifice. I suppose it *could* be used to describe "hard work" but it isn't usually used this way. Working hard isn't usually described as a personal sacrifice unless it involves something out of the ordinary such as exceptionally long hours or over a very long period of time. You normally *lose* something in exchange to be described as "paying a price".

Although it isn't very exciting, I would personally just say:

> ... producing things *is very difficult for him*, or sometimes *not possible* at all.

Better to avoid using an idiom at all than use it incorrectly.

Other idioms/metaphors that describe great effort include:

> ... producing things *takes everything he has*...
>
> ... producing things *is an all-out effort*...
>
> ... producing things *is an uphill battle*...

Comment: Do you know any idiom that would describe a very hard psychological effort - like the case described in my example?

Comment: @brilliant Added a few to my answer.